# sending data efficiently between 2 bluetooth modules via arduino

Tags: bluetooth, arduino

I'm able to pair and send data no problem, but i've come across an issue where the receiver will receive and interpret the data byte by byte instead of a string of bytes. This is a problem because we are the data sent are values read from a potentiometer. If the potentiometer changes too fast, the receiver isnt able to read the changes fast enough. Any suggestions on how to do this?

My current setup is an HC-05 paired with a HC-06, powered by 2 arduino micros. Baud rate of sender is 30400 and receiver 9600(i have no idea why 30400 wont work on the receiver).

Answer (score 0):

Having different Baud Rates of two units communicating using a serial interface is usually not a good idea. Why can't you set the sender baud rate to 9600? If you can, that's where I recommend you start. Also, if you could post your code, that would be great.

Comment: will post soon... when i change the baud rate of the sender, garbage is received on the receiving end, which is interesting